# Invalid datetime format in python-mysql query

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, datetime

I wanted to fetch a record from database which is having the `datetime` field a part of primary key. I am querying from `python` using `mysqldb package` which is resulting in error

> Invalid datetime format

wherein the same query is working fine when executed through command line and mysql workbench.

My code looks like this.

```
def get_all_list(table_name, modify_dt, params):
    cursr = connections['default'].cursor()
    stmt = 'select * from ' + table_name + ' where ' + params 
    cursr.execute(stmt)
    data = cursr.fetchall()
```

the params is the string which contains my primary key value.

for instance

```
params is "join_date = '2016-09-08 00:00:00+00:00'"
```

my final query looks similiar to this

```
select * from employee where join_date = '2016-09-08 00:00:00+00:00'
```

When executed, the same is providing result in mysql workbench while when executed through my program , I am getting error as

> Incorrect datetime value: '2016-09-08 00:00:00+00:00' for column
>   'join_date' at row 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Date format should be

```
'2016-09-08 00:00:00'
```

if you need to set time zone, you need a separate SQL query

```
set time_zone='+00:00';
```

See also:  [How do I set the time zone of MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930900/how-to-set-time-zone-of-mysql)

---

If you are using django, you can set time_zone for the entire app in the settings file:

```
DATABASES['default'] = {
    'ENGINE': 'your_db_engine',
    'NAME': 'my_database',
    'USER': 'username',
    'PASSWORD': 'password',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': 3306,
    'OPTIONS': {
        "init_command": "SET storage_engine=InnoDB; set time_zone='+00:00';",
    },
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. But where am i supposed to set the time_zone for my app.. Should it be in my settings.py file

Comment: Are you using django?

Comment: Hey.. thanks for the above update but i am not using default storage engine currently. Also, when i am trying to set it, it is showing unknown system variable storage_engine.

Comment: The issue is resolved when i used USE_TZ = False in my settings.py